# OpenERP multi company Chart of accounts selected company charts not listed

Tags: openerp-7, accounting

In Accounting main menu, when I click **chart of accounts** as admin, the criteria popup will come.  I have selected Company C's fiscal period among A, B and C.  But when I click **open charts** by default the company A's charts will be listed (Alphabetical order of companies names).  I can change the company drop down and see C's charts.

But I want to open C's charts by default, since I selected C's fiscal year and periods in Criteria.

Also I want to know if the charts (P & L and Balance sheet) can be by default unfolded.  If so please guide me.

Comment: Still not able to find a solution.  Any one there to SOS.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a custom module to do this functionality.  In the chart of account tree xml remove the toolbar="1". Now you can view the all companies in tree view instead of dropdown. Now you have to apply domain filter through your custom module to restrict companies.

Also check the account module wizard directory to view the popup python code.